# iOS - Get container view content dynamic height

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uistackview, uicontainerview

In my application using ContainerView, which contains below Things

- StackView

  - UIView
  - TableView
  - UIView

In some cases, I have to hide views, tableview. With below settings, I am able to show the container view with dynamic height

- `view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`
- With `UITableView` `contentSize` observer by changing tableview height.

But here I am unable to get the dynamic height of the containerView content.

I have tried below options to get container view content height but no luck

- `containerView.frame.size.height`
- `containerView.bounds.size.height`
- `stackView.frame.size.height`
- `stackView.bounds.size.height`
- using `setNeedsLayout()` with containterView, stackView before getting height
- calling `layoutIfNeeded()` with containterView, stackView before getting height
- trying to get containView, stackView height in `override func viewDidLayoutSubviews()`, `override func viewWillLayoutSubviews()`

Comment: If you are using constraints and auto-layout, the "dynamic height" of the container will be `containerView.frame.height`. But... why do you need the height to begin with?

Comment: What are you getting in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`function?

Comment: @NeilGaliaskarov: in all cases after hiding any view in stack view or eventhough if  tableview content size in increases. Before and after i am getting height is same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found an answer, below are the steps to achieve the solution

- for StackView we have to set the bottom constraint as `>= 0`.
- After hiding any view within the StackView, we have to apply `stackView.setNeedsLayout(), stackView.layoutIfNeeded()` these on StackView
- Now if you print the stack view frame it will show the updated frame result.